# C Console - Printing pattern on the same line

Tags: c, console

I'm trying different activities as I am a beginner and want to learn more. I'm trying to print a pattern on the same line my code is:

```
int main()
{
    int numOfWiggles;
    int count;
    printf("Enter number of wiggles: ");
    scanf("%d", &numOfWiggles);
    printf("_");
    for (count=1; count<=numOfWiggles; count++)
    {
        printf("/\\ \n   \\/ \r");
    }
    printf("-");
}
```

EDITED OUT.

But instead of getting them on a new line, I'm wanting the pattern to extend across the same line only. I know it's because `\n`but I have no idea how to get it all on the same line.

Comment: you need 2 for loops for this. first to print upper half and second for the lower half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can divide it into 2 part upper and lower.
to print upper half use:

```
for (count=1; count<=numOfWiggles; count++)
{
    printf("/\\  ");  //this will print /\  /\  /\
}
printf("\n  ");   // go to next line
```

to print lower half use:

```
for (count=1; count<=numOfWiggles; count++)
{
    if(count == numOfWiggles)
        printf(" \\/");  // this will print last \/ without space at the end
    else
        printf(" \\/ ");  // this will print \/ \/ \/
}
```

you are using'\n' which will take cursor position to next line and start printing from the next line which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are looking for is actually the result of two printing on two different lines. You could construct the strings in the same loop with buffers or just use two loops.

```
for (count = 0; count <  numOfWiggles; count++)
{
    If (count == 0)
        Printf ("_/\");
    Else
        Printf ("  /\");
    Printf ("  _/n");
}

for (count = 0; count <  numOfWiggles; count++)
{
    If (count == 0)
        Printf ("   \/");
    Else
        Printf ("  \/");
    Printf ("/n");
}
```

Comment: This also works, appreciate it and an interesting way